# Bash getopts take more positional parameters after the first argument

Tags: bash, getopts

So I don't know how to make getopts so that it takes every positional parameter after the argument.

What I mean by this, is the following: this is my example code:

```
#!/bin/bash
while getopts 'a:b:' thing_here; do
        case $thing_here in
                a) part_1="${OPTARG}" ;;
                b) part_2="${OPTARG}" ;;
                *) echo "invalid option, quitting"
                        exit 1 ;;
        esac
done

echo "part 1 = ${part_1}"
echo "part 2 = ${part_2}"
```

Now what I want is the following:
Input:

```
$: ./example_script.sh -a asd qwe zxc -b dfg 213
```

Output:

```
part 1 = asd qwe zxc
part 2 = dfg 213
```

But what I actually get, is the following:

```
part 1 = asd
part 2 =
```

Now I know I can do what I want to do here by enclosing the arguments as such:

```
$: ./example_script.sh -a 'asd qwe zxc' -b 'dfg 213'
```

But what I'm trying to find, is how to do this within the script and getopts itself, without having to put the quotes myself (easier for some automation).

Comment: Possible duplicate, or at least related anyway, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7529856/retrieving-multiple-arguments-for-a-single-option-using-getopts-in-bash

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to enclose the args in quotes (the simplest and most robust solution), then you can't use `getopts`, and you have to hack something together like:

```
declare -A args
key=""
for arg; do
    case $arg in
        "-a") key=part_1 ;;
        "-b") key=part_2 ;;
        *)  [[ -n $key ]] || { echo "unexpected argument" >&2; exit 1; }
            args[$key]="${args[$key]}$arg "
            ;;
    esac
done
# turn the array keys into variables
for key in "${!args[@]}"; do declare "$key=${args[$key]% }"; done
echo "part 1 => $part_1"
echo "part 2 => $part_2"
```

---

With your requirements, you cannot use `getopt` either. Assuming you have GNU getopt, watch what happens:

```
$ set --  -a asd qwe zxc -b dfg 213
$ getopt -o a:b: -- "$@"
 -a 'asd' -b 'dfg' -- 'qwe' 'zxc' '213'
```

Only the first word after the option is acquired as the option's argument.

I repeat, take the easy route and ensure the arguments are quoted.

Comment: Is there any other solution? I looked for a bit, and 'getopt' seems to be an older, but more powerful tool. I don't know if it can achieve this, but if it can, I might start learning it.

Comment: Look for the getopt example file on your system, it's very instructive: `locate getopt-parse.bash`